# What does this symbol mean next to someones name?

Tags: gears-of-war-4

Occasionally, I will see this symbol (circled in the picture below) next to someones name in the "who killed who and how" section that scrolls in the bottom left of the screen.  What does it mean?  It doesn't appear that often.

[image: Symbol]

Comment: It means you are their nemesis or they are your nemesis.  I am trying to find which symbol means what now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I was able to test this in a private match.  That symbol means that you killed them at least 5 times in a row without them killing you, making you their nemesis.  You should also receive the nemesis ribbon.

Here are my screenshots from testing.

Just after killing the bot 5 times in a row, the symbol appears:

[image]

I let the bot kill me once then I killed him right after it.  I no longer saw that symbol.

[image]

[image]

The inverse of this will show a skull next to your name when that player kills you 5 times in a row and will show a special marker over their head when you use the shade-like display(LB by default on xbox) once they are spotted.